# How to calculate measure using a date column?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have a dataset like this.

```
Sprint     Story      Date Created(mm-dd-yyy)

AA          1             1/1/2021

AA          2             1/2/2021

AA          3              1/7/2021

BB          4              1/15/2021

BB          5              1/18/2021

BB          6              1/22/2021
```

I want to calculate the total count of stories(measure) using the max start date and adding 3 days to that date, so for example the out come from the above dataset should be..

max current start date=1/22/2021 and adding 3 days it will be 1/25/2021 so the total story count between this two days will be one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following DAX and if it helps then accept it as the answer.

Create a calculated column as follows:

```
    Count Sprint =
    VAR spr = Table[Sprint]
    VAR x =
        IF (
            Table[Created Date].[Day] < 4,
            CALCULATE (
                COUNTA ( Table[Story] ),
                FILTER ( ALL ( Table[Sprint] ), Table[Sprint] = spr )
             ),
             IF (
                Table[Created Date].[Day] > 14 && Table[Created Date].[Day] < 19,
            CALCULATE (
                   COUNTA ( Jhon[Story] ),
                   FILTER ( ALL ( Table[Sprint] ), Table[Sprint] = spr )
                  )
             )
         )
    RETURN
        x
```

This should give you the desired result.

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you for sharing but the requirement changed...what I am looking now is getting the max start date and count the stories under that sprint based by adding 3 days from the max start date..for example VAR CurrentSprintStartDate = CALCULATE(Max(Sprints[Created Date]),Filter(Sprints,Sprints[InCurrentSprint]=1))

1. get the max start date and add 3 days and count the stories that are between max start date and 3 days after. e.g if max start date is 5/26/2021 then count all between 5/26/2021 and 5/29/2021.

Comment: @Jhon, Can you elaborate little more with some input and expected output data

Comment: @Jhon I have added another answer, can you look and let me know if it's working for you or not? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have updated your question here is another answer for it, if it helps mark it as an answer.

1. Create a new date column that increments the `Created date` by 3 days

   ```
   New Date = Table[Created Date].[Date] + 3
   ```
2. Add another calculated column that only counts the no. of sprints between the last `Create date` and 3 days after that, with the following DAX:

   ```
   New Count Sprint = 
   VAR Max_Date = MAX(Table[Created Date])

   RETURN 
         IF(Table[New Date] > Max_Date , 1, 0)
   ```

This should give you the desired result.

[image: Output]